# Sending column name to procedure and reduce value by one

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I need to make a procedure to reduce the stock of a certain item by one every time it's executed. The issue comes from wanting to do it the old way, and can't seem to think of any other method. This is the code I wrote right now:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE REDUCESTOCK
@cod_ag numeric(3), //Agency code
@tipo_stock char(1), //Stock to be altered (Merchandising or Artifact)
@producto varchar(5) //Name of the product (Column name)
AS
BEGIN
IF(@tipo_stock='A')
    UPDATE JS_ELECTRODOMESTICO
    SET @producto=@producto-1
    WHERE cod_ag=@cod_ag
ELSE
    PRINT 'error'
END
GO
```

I get an error since, of course, I can't convert a varchar into int.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the amount of stock stored?  Certainly not in the product name field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to specify the column name in the 'producto' parameter? If so, you'll need to build a 'dynamic SQL' string and execute it...

```
IF(@tipo_stock='A')
  declare @sqlcmd varchar(max);
  set @sqlcmd = 'UPDATE JS_ELECTRODOMESTICO SET '
    +@producto+'='+@producto+'-1 WHERE cod_ag='+@cod_ag;
  exec (@sqlcmd);
```

Comment: Thank you, I googled dynamic SQL and managed to find some ways to solve it.